# Need to handle push notification both for remote and local in foreground without user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I have been implemented local and remote notification both were works when app is in **background**. User will tap on any notification and everything work fine.

But when app is in **foreground mode** . **didReceiveRemoteNotification** delegate not fired automatically when app receive a remote notification. In this situation user need to interact/tap on notification, but I want app will detect without user interaction.

Below is code I am using to schedule for local notification.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}
```

But If comment it above line, app will start detecting remote notification without user interaction in foreground. But I need this behaviour with local notification.

Below is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    ScheduleLocalNotifications().scheduleNotification()

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    return true
}
```

// Remote notification Handling

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let jsonResult = userInfo["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    print(jsonResult["alert"] ?? "Not Found")
}
```

//Local notification handling

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    }
```

Comment: share your didfinish and delegate methods  code.

Comment: I have update my question with didfinish code